# Log in ADT Layout Editor

Tags: android, adt

I'm designing my own View which doesn't behave as I want.

I want to add some debugging output that I can see when the view is previewed in the ADT Layout Editor.

Is it possible?

Comment: log will not show you errors in Layout Editor.by hovering mouse to point of error will let u know waht actual error is...

Comment: its not an RuntimeException its a Logical Error not rendering as i want. Right now i thrown a Exception with log i want to see.

Comment: Seems like a pretty clear question to me. OP want's to know if there is an alternative to Log.i that actually works in Layout Preview mode. Not sure why this was closed. If only I knew the answer...

Answer (score -1):

Open the Error Log `Window > Show View > Error Log`

That will contain the errors you're having with the ADT Layout Editor.

Also, please mark all your existing questions with an answer - you have a very low answer rate.

Comment: I dont have any Exception in my own View. There is a logical error its not draw as i wanted. I need to log so that i can find out what my calculation are going wrong. Its difficult to debug using Emulator. And my none of the question were being answered completely. If u have the answer for my questions, then I will mark that as answered.

Comment: From your original question I never would have inferred that what you actually wanted. You need to write your questions in a more explanatory way. That is why you don't have any answers to your questions.